# Jquery - function is not being called when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am changing the `innerHTML` of a div and then with a newly created `HTML` i am calling a function, but for some reason, that function is not being called. Below is my work. Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z725dpLa/1/)

```js
$('#click1').click(function () {
    $('#submit').html('this is new html <br /><a href="javascript:;" id= "click2">Click here 2nd</a>')

});

$('#click2').click(function(){
alert("all is well");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="submit">
    <a href = "javascript:;" id="click1">Click here</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please put the relevant code here.  You will get better and quicker responses.

Comment: Because click2 doesn't exist when you attempt to attach the event to it.

Comment: Please include relevant information in the question. A fiddle is nice, but it's extra. Also, you can include code snippets in your question in a Fiddle-like runnable way using the Code Snippet button.

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is you are assigning an event handler to an object that doesn't yet exist. Simply move the click2 event handler into the click event handler like so.

```
$('#click1').click(function () {
    $('#submit').html('this is new html <br /><a href="javascript:;" id="click2">Click here 2nd</a>')
    $('#click2').click(function(){
    alert("all is well");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you generated `click2` dynamically so you should [***delegate***](http://www.sitepoint.com/event-delegation-with-jquery/). Try this

```
$('#submit').on('click', '#click2',function(){
    alert("all is well");
});
```

Comment: Yes-yes, 40 reputation is temptation, and so on, but why not just mark question as duplicate one? Not only this question was asked several thousand times, but there also are good explanations why delegated event handlers should be used in SO, not just "try this".

Answer (score 0):

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z725dpLa/5/)

```
$(document).on('click','#click2',function(){
  alert("all is well");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<div id="submit">
    <a href="#" id="button1">Click here</a>
</div>
```

js

```
$('#button1').on('click', function(){
    $(this).replaceWith('HTML HERE');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z725dpLa/6/

Comment: How does it help in original question situation with dynamically created element?

Answer (score 0):

You can't attach EventHandlers to DOM-Elements which are not created. Therefore you need to attach your `click2`-Handler after inserting your new Link into the DOM!

```
$('#click1').click(function () {

    $('#submit').html('this is new html <br /><a href="javascript:;" id= "click2">Click here 2nd</a>');
    $('#click2').click(function(){
      alert("all is well");
    });
});
```

Comment: Please explain your answer